# When are dependent asset copied to a bundles in Unity Addressable System?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i'm using unity addressable system.
My understanding is that when i have bundles A and B, and i have assets that are simultaneously dependent on certain assets in A and certain assets in B, they are copied to both bundles when the bundle is built.  (From what I've read in various blog posts.)

So for testing this case, i had made 2 image object prefabs. And those are using same image sprite.

[image]

Then i had made these as a addressable resources.
(Inspector > addressable checked)

[image]

Then i had made 3 another bundles and labels, and put those assets(Prefabs and image) in each bundles.

[image]

As you know that Image1 and Image2 prefab use the test.png image (sprite). So it means they have dependencies for SharedTest bundle. (Label C)

Then i write a test code like below.

```
 private IEnumerator CoStartGame()
 {

     var test1 = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("Assets/AddressableResources/Battles/Image1.prefab");
     yield return test1;

     var test2 = Addressables.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("Assets/AddressableResources/Battles/Image2.prefab");
     yield return test2;

     var test3 = test1.Result; //Loaded Success
     var test4 = test2.Result; //Loaded Success
            
 }
```

But in addressable analyze window, there is no any duplicate issues.

[image]

I'm confused. It looks like test.png, which I thought would be copied and included in both A and B bundles, is not being copied. Is test.png not copied to bundle A and bundle B because it is in the local bundle?

My guess is that for bundles that are downloaded from Remote Path, you can't see the dependencies before you download them, so you have no choice but to copy all the assets that depend on them.
However, I think this happens because the local bundles already understand each other's references, is this correct?

(Ultimately, I want to group assets with these dependencies into separate SharedBundles to avoid duplicate bundling. Does this automatically prevent duplicates even if I don't do anything?)

[p.s]
As I continued testing, It seems that the duplication issue was caused by dependencies on resources in the Resource folder.

There doesn't seem to be any duplicate inclusion issues between bundles using addressables, even if there are dependencies each others.

Comment: I found this tool which might help you: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.assetbundlebrowser@1.6/manual/index.html disclaimer: I have no experience with it

Comment: @bolov Thanks for providing such a great tool, but I'd like to understand the real mechanics a bit more. (I'm curious about the issue with bundled copying of resources and would like to get an answer to that, and horrifyingly none of the documentation covers the detailed inner workings of this. )